# Django how to select data from db filtering by list index - PUserSlidertxt.objects.filter(username=p[2])

Tags: python, django, select, filter

In views.py:

```
def main(request):
    .....
    divvs = [str(i) for i in range(3)]
    members = {}
    p = []
    for divv in divvs:
    members[divv] = PUserSlidertxt.objects.filter(ostan=os, shahr=sh, senf=senf)
    p = PUser.objects.values('username')
    asdf = PUserSlidertxt.objects.filter(username=p[2])
    .....
```

But this line does not work:

```
    asdf = PUserSlidertxt.objects.filter(username=p[2])
```

So how should I edit it?

=====

By using `{{ p }}` in the html file we can see:

> [{'username': 'respina'}, {'username': 'mahtab'}, {'username':
>   'shargh'}, {'username': 'tehran'}, {'username': 'sayyare'},
>   {'username': 'lutus'}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`p[2]` is a dictionary* with a `username` key - in other words, what Django tries to filter and fails:

```
asdf = PUserSlidertxt.objects.filter(username={'username': 'shargh'})
```

Instead, you can either *unpack the dictionary*:

```
asdf = PUserSlidertxt.objects.filter(**p[2])
```

Or, get the value by the key explicitly:

```
asdf = PUserSlidertxt.objects.filter(username=p[2]['username'])
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in template, p in you view is a list of dictionaries. So you have to specify not only index, but also a key:

```
asdf = PUserSlidertxt.objects.filter(username=p[2]['username'])
```